# "writing to a file" procedure in x86 (MASM) assembly not displaying correct data

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm, kernel32

I have a WriteFileContents procedure that was provided to me from my instructor. It's suppose to write data to a file, but Chinese characters are being displayed in the text file produced and not the original english text. Also when I enter data using option 1 then chose to save it to file, nothing is saved in the generated file. In this snippet of my program I have 3 operations.

1. to read data from the console and store it
2. to read data from a file and store it
3. take stored data and write it to a file.

the data to be written to the file is stored in the variable fdata.

the key procedures in play are *WriteFileContents* and *Update_fdata*
I debugged several times and wasn't able to pinpoint the issue.
I don't know why the text is displaying incorrectly.

---

```
title prog.asm                          ;DOS file name of program

.586                                    ;enable all pentium instructions
.model flat, stdcall                    ;memory model & calling convention
.stack 8192                             ;allocate 8k for stack

INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib                 ;Include the kernel 32 library

;----------------------------------------------------------
; Constant Definitions
;----------------------------------------------------------

MAX_LINE  equ 80
BUF_SIZE equ 240

STD_INPUT  equ -10d                     ;Function number for keyboard input
STD_OUTPUT equ -11d                     ;Function number for monitor output

LF equ 10d                              ;Line feed ascii constant
CR equ 13d                              ;Carriage return constant
NEWLINE equ CR,LF                       ;Combine CR and LF for carriage return

ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT  equ 1           ;Flag to turn off line buffering
ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT equ 1           ;Flag to turn off line bufferin
ENABLE_LINE_WRAP        equ 3           ;Flag to trun line wrap on
DISABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT equ 7           ;Flag to turn on line buffering

CREATE_NEW    EQU  1                    ;Parameter for creating a new file
CREATE_ALWAYS EQU  2                    ;Always create (overwrite existing)
OPEN_EXISTING EQU  3                    ;Parameter for opening an existing file
GENERIC_READ  EQU  80000000h            ;Parameter for reading a file
GENERIC_WRITE EQU  40000000h            ;Parameter for writing a file

FILE_SHARE_READ   equ 1
FILE_SHARE_WRITE  equ 2
FILE_SHARE_DELETE equ 4

FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL equ 80h
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE equ 0FFFFFFFFh
HANDLE equ dword

;----------------------------------------------------------
; prototype Declarations for libarary imports
;----------------------------------------------------------

ExitProcess proto,
dwExitCode:dword                   ;The exit code for the process 

GetStdHandle proto, 
nStdHandle: dword                  ;The standard device. -10=INPUT, -11=OUTPUT, -13=ERROR

SetConsoleMode proto,                  
hConsoleHandle:dword,              ;A handle to the console input buffer or a console screen buffer
dwMode:dword                       ;The input or output mode to be set. 

ReadFile proto, 
hFile:dword,                       ;A handle to the device
lpBuffer:near32,                   ;A pointer to the buffer that receives the data read 
nNumberOfCharsToRead:dword,        ;The maximum number of bytes to be read.
lpNumberOfbytesRead:near32,        ;A pointer to the variable that receives the number of bytes read
lpOverlapped:near32                ;A pointer to an OVERLAPPED structure is required if the hFile parameter 
                                   ;was opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, otherwise it can be NULL.


WriteFile proto,                  
hFile:dword, lpBuffer:near32,      ;A handle to the device
nNumberOfCharsToWrite:dword,       ;The maximum number of bytes to be written.
lpNumberOfbytesWritten:near32,     ;A pointer to the variable that receives the number of bytes written
lpOverlapped:near32                ;A pointer to an OVERLAPPED structure is required if the hFile parameter 
                                   ;was opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, otherwise it can be NULL.

CloseHandle proto,                     ;Prototype for closing a file
fHandle:dword

GetLastError proto                     ;Prototype for getting specific error

CreateFileA proto,                     ;Prototype for CreateFile, used for getting handle to new or existin file
lpFileName:near32,
dwDesiredAccess:dword,
dwShareMode:dword,
lpSecurityAttributes:near32,
dwCreationDisposition:dword,
dwFlagsAndAttributes:dword,
hTemplateFile:dword

GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo proto,
hConsoleOutput:dword,               ; A handle to the console screen buffer. 
lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo:near32    ; A pointer to a CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO structure

FillConsoleOutputCharacterA proto,
hConsoleOutput:dword,               ; A handle to the console screen buffer. 
cCharacter:byte,                    ; The character to be written to the console screen buffer.
nLength:dword,                      ; The number of character cells to which the character should be written.
dwWriteCoord:dword,                 ; A COORD structure that specifies the character coordinates of the first cell
lpNumberOfCharsWritten:near32       ; A pointer to a variable that receives the number of characters actually written

SetConsoleCursorPosition proto,
hConsoleOutput:dword,               ; A handle to the console screen buffer. 
dwCursorPosition:dword              ; new cursor position,




;----------------------------------------------------------
; Data Segment -- Global Variables
;----------------------------------------------------------

.data
strAddr         dd  ?
strLength       dd  ?
hStdOut         dd  ?
hStdIn          dd  ?
hFileOut        dd  ?
hFileIn         dd  ?
read            dd  ?
written         dd  ?   
coord           dd  0
scrnBufInfo     db 22 DUP(0)
inFilename      db 256 dup(0)
outFilename     db 256 dup(0)
fdata           db BUF_SIZE dup(0)
numBytes        dd ?

newlineStr      db NEWLINE, 0       ;string for printing newline
filePrompt      db "Enter filename: ",0
mnuItem1        db "1) Enter new line",NEWLINE,0
mnuItem2        db "2) Read from file",NEWLINE,0
mnuItem3        db "3) Save to File",NEWLINE,0
mnuItem4        db "4) Exit",NEWLINE,0
mnuPrompt       db ": ",0
invalidOption   db "Invalid Option! ",0
continuePrompt  db "Press enter key to continue...",NEWLINE,0
fileError       db "Error reading file!",NEWLINE,0
goodbyeMsg      db "Goodbye.", NEWLINE, 0
enterDataMsg    db "Enter data:",NEWLINE,0
enterOutfilename     db "Enter a name for file:",NEWLINE,0
newData         db BUF_SIZE dup(0)
sectNum1        word 0              ;for holding the section number entered by user 
sectNum2        word 0              ;for holding the section number entered by user 
outData         db BUF_SIZE dup(0)  ; the finished string to be displayed
tempData        db BUF_SIZE dup(0)  ; extra string for temperary holding
sepStr          db "-------------------------------------", NEWLINE, 0
zeroStr         db "0", 0
spaceStr        db " ",0
hexStr          db "0x", 0

input1          db 80d dup(0)       ;buffer for user input
output1         db 80d dup(0)       ;buffer for output strings

console_buffer_info db 22 dup(0)
topLeft dword 0


;----------------------------------------------------------
; Code Segment
;----------------------------------------------------------

.code
main proc

MainLoop:

    ; zero out registers
    xor eax, eax                    ; zero out eax
    xor ebx, ebx                    ; zero out ebx
    xor ecx, ecx                    ; zero out ecx
    xor edx, edx                    ; zero out edx


    lea esi, newlineStr 
    call PrintString

    lea esi, sepStr
    call PrintString

    call DisplayMenu

    ; get Menu Option
    lea edi, input1
    call GetString

    cmp input1, '1'
    je option1

    cmp input1, '2'
    je option2

    cmp input1, '3'
    je option3

    cmp input1, '4'
    je Exit

    ; invalid option entered
    lea esi, invalidOption
    call PrintString
    call PauseForEnter

    jmp MainLoop

option1:

    ;display enter data prompt
    lea esi, enterDataMsg
    call PrintString

    ;get data from stdin
    lea edi, outData 
    call GetString

    ;copy outData back to fdata
    call Update_fdata

    ;clear display and display data at top 
    call ClearScreen
    lea esi, fdata
    call PrintString
    jmp MainLoop


option2:

    ; prompt for filename to read
    lea esi, filePrompt
    call PrintString

    ; read filename from console
    lea edi, inFilename
    call GetString

    ; read file data
    call ReadFileContents

    ;clear display and display data at top 
    call ClearScreen
    lea esi, fdata
    call PrintString
    jmp MainLoop



option3:

    ;prompt to enter outFile name
    lea esi, enterOutfilename
    call PrintString

    ;get the outFile name
    lea edi, outFilename
    call GetString

    ;copy outData back to fdata
    call Update_fdata

    ;call WriteFileContents to save file
    call WriteFileContents

    ;clear display and display data at top 
    call ClearScreen
    lea esi, fdata
    call PrintString
    jmp MainLoop


Exit:

    lea esi, goodbyeMsg
    call PrintString


    invoke ExitProcess, 0           ;exit process with no error

main endp


;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Procedure to copy outData into fdata
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Update_fdata  proc                ; Define procedure
        pushad                     ; save all registers
        pushfd                     ; save flags

        lea esi, outData
        lea edi, fdata

        ;Copy Section
        Update_fdata_loop1:
            cmp byte ptr [esi], 0
            je done_Update_fdata

            mov al, [esi]
            mov [edi], al
            inc esi
            inc edi 

        jmp Update_fdata_loop1
        ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

        done_Update_fdata:
        mov al, 0
        mov [edi], al       ;end EDI with null terminator


        popfd                      ; restore flags
        popad                      ; restore registers
        ret                        ; return to caller
Update_fdata   endp




;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Procedure to clear the screen
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ClearScreen proc
        pushad                     ; save all registers
        pushfd                     ; save flags

        ; HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        invoke GetStdHandle,STD_OUTPUT ; get handle for console output
        mov    hStdOut, eax        ; copy file handle for screen

        ; GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(console, &screen);
        invoke GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo,hStdOut,near32 ptr console_buffer_info

        ; FillConsoleOutputCharacterA(console, ' ', screen.dwSize.X * screen.dwSize.Y, topLeft, &written);
        xor eax, eax
        xor ebx, ebx
        mov ax, word ptr console_buffer_info
        mov bx, word ptr console_buffer_info+2
        mul bx
        invoke FillConsoleOutputCharacterA,hStdOut,' ',eax,topLeft,near32 ptr written

        ; SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, topLeft);
        invoke SetConsoleCursorPosition,hStdOut,topLeft

        popfd                      ; restore flags
        popad                      ; restore registers
        ret                        ; return to caller
ClearScreen endp


;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Procedure to display the menu
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DisplayMenu proc

lea esi, sepStr
call PrintString

; Option 1: enter new line
lea esi, mnuItem1
call PrintString

; Option 2: save to file
lea esi, mnuItem2
call PrintString

; Option 3: Exit
lea esi, mnuItem3
call PrintString

; Option 4: Exit
lea esi, mnuItem4
call PrintString

lea esi, mnuPrompt
call PrintString


        ret                        ; return to caller
DisplayMenu endp

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Procedure to read file
; [IN] inFilename
; [OUT] file contents in fdata
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ReadFileContents  proc                 ; Define procedure
        pushad                     ; save all registers
        pushfd                     ; save flags

        ; zero buffer out
        lea edi, fdata             ; point edi at buffer to be zero'd out
        xor eax, eax               ; put zero into accumulator to write to buffer
        mov cx, BUF_SIZE           ; put buf size into counter
        rep stosb                  ; now fill buffer

        ; open file for reading
        invoke CreateFileA, near32 ptr inFilename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
           0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0
        mov hFileIn, eax           ; save file handle

        ; see if we got an error opening file
        cmp eax, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
        je error_ReadFileContents

        mov ecx, BUF_SIZE          ; string length
        lea edi, fdata             ; load address of fdata into edi

        invoke ReadFile,           ; invoke standard ReadFile with
          eax,                     ;   file handle for keyboard
          edi,                     ;   address of location to write file contents
          ecx,                     ;   length of string
          near32 ptr read,         ;   variable for # bytes read
          0                        ;   overlapped mode

        invoke CloseHandle, hFileIn; close file handle

        ; display # bytes read
        mov eax, read               ; move num bytes read into eax, so we can save to variable
        mov numBytes, eax           ; now save value from eax into permanent variable
        ;lea esi, read              ; point esi at num bytes read for converting to string
        ;mov ebx, 10                ; set our number base to base 10
        ;lea edi, output1           ; point edit at location to store string
        ;call Num2Str               ; now convert number to a string
        ;mov esi, edi               ; now point esi at that string to display
        ;call PrintString           ; display the string
        ;lea esi, bytesReadStr      ; point esi at " bytes read." string
        ;call PrintString           ; display it
        jmp done_ReadFileContents  ; jump over error handling section

error_ReadFileContents:
        lea esi, fileError         ; point esi at file read error message
        call PrintString           ; now display the message

done_ReadFileContents:
        popfd                      ; restore flags
        popad                      ; restore registers
        ret                        ; return to caller
ReadFileContents   endp

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Procedure to write data to file
; [IN] file contents in fdata
; [IN] outFilename
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WriteFileContents  proc                ; Define procedure
        pushad                     ; save all registers
        pushfd                     ; save flags

        invoke CreateFileA, near32 ptr outFilename, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
           0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0
        mov hFileOut, eax

        lea esi, fdata
        invoke WriteFile,          ; invoke standard WriteFile with
          hFileOut,                ;   file handle for screen
          esi,                     ;   address of string
          numBytes,                ;   length of string
          near32 ptr written,      ;   variable for # bytes written
          0                        ;   overlapped mode          

        invoke CloseHandle, hFileOut; close file handle

        ; display number of bytes written
        ;lea esi, numBytes          ; point esi at num bytes read for converting to string
        ;mov ebx, 10                ; set our number base to base 10
        ;lea edi, output1           ; point edit at location to store string
        ;call Num2Str              ; now convert number to a string
        ;mov esi, edi               ; now point esi at that string to display
        ;call PrintString           ; display the string
        ;lea esi, bytesWriteStr     ; point esi at " bytes written." string
        ;call PrintString           ; display it

        popfd                      ; restore flags
        popad                      ; restore registers
        ret                        ; return to caller
WriteFileContents   endp

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Procedure to prompt user to press enter to continue
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PauseForEnter proc
        lea esi, continuePrompt    ; point esi at string to prompt user to continue
        call PrintString           ; display prompt
        lea esi, input1            ; point esi at location for user input
        call GetString             ; get user input from console
        ret                        ; return to caller
PauseForEnter endp

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Procedure to print a string to stdout
;
; Given   :  The Address of Null (0) terminated String to print in ESI register
; process :  Print the String using the kernel32.lib WriteFile to
;         :  Standard_Output function call.  No registers are changed and the
;         :  flags are not affected.
; Return  :  Nothing
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PrintString proc                       ; Define procedure
        pushad                     ; save registers
        pushfd                     ; save flags
        mov    strAddr, esi        ; copy string address
                                   ; find string length
        mov    strLength, 0        ; initialize string length
WhileChar:  cmp    byte ptr [esi], 0   ; character = null?
        jz     EndWhileChar        ; exit if so
        inc    strLength           ; increment character count
        inc    esi                 ; point at next character
        jmp    WhileChar           ; while more characters exist
EndWhileChar:
        invoke GetStdHandle,STD_OUTPUT ; get handle for console output
        mov    hStdOut, eax        ; copy file handle for screen
        invoke WriteFile,          ; invoke standard WriteFile with
          hStdOut,                 ;   file handle for screen
          strAddr,                 ;   address of string
          strLength,               ;   length of string
          near32 ptr written,      ;   variable for # bytes written
          0                        ;   overlapped mode
        popfd                      ; restore flags
        popad                      ; restore registers
        ret                        ; return to caller
PrintString endp




;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Procedure to get a string from stdin
;
; Given   :  The Address of the String to fill in EDI register
; process :  Input the String using the kernel32.lib ReadFile from the
;         :  Standard_Input function call.  No registers are changed and the
;         :  flags are not affected.
; Return  :  The input string in the data segment
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GetString proc                         ; Define procedure
        pushad                     ; save all registers
        pushfd                     ; save flags

        invoke GetStdHandle,STD_INPUT  ; get handle for console
        mov    hStdIn, eax         ; save the handle
        invoke SetConsoleMode,     ; invoke standard console with
          hStdIn,                  ;   file handle for keyboard
          DISABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT  ;   turn line buffering on

        mov    ecx, 255d;MAXSTR    ; string length
        mov    strLength, ecx      ; maximum string to accept
        mov    strAddr, edi        ; save pointer to input string
        invoke ReadFile,           ; invoke standard ReadFile with
          hStdIn,                  ;   file handle for keyboard
          strAddr,                 ;   address of string
          strLength,               ;   length of string
          near32 ptr read,         ;   variable for # bytes read
          0                        ;   overlapped mode

        mov ecx, read            
        mov byte ptr [edi+ecx-2],0 ; replace CR/LF by trailing null

        popfd                      ; restore flags
        popad                      ; restore registers
        ret                        ; return to caller
GetString   endp



;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Procedure to print a character to the console
;
; Given   :  The Address of the Character to print in ESI register
; Process :  Print the Character using the kernel32.lib WriteFile to
;         :  Standard_Output function call.  No registers are changed and the
;         :  flags are not affected.
; Return  :  Nothing
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PutChar PROC NEAR32                         ; Define procedure
        pushad                          ; save registers
        pushfd                          ; save flags
        INVOKE GetStdHandle,STD_OUTPUT  ; get handle for console output
        mov hStdOut, eax                ; copy file handle for screen
    INVOKE SetConsoleMode,          ; invoke standard console with
        hStdOut,                        ;   file handle for screen
        ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT     ;   turn line buffering off
    INVOKE WriteFile,               ; invoke standard WriteFile with
        hStdOut,                        ;   file handle for screen
        esi,                            ;   address of character
        1,                              ;   length of one byte
        NEAR32 PTR written,             ;   variable for # bytes written
        0                               ;   overlapped mode
        popfd                           ; restore flags
        popad                           ; restore registers
        ret                             ; return to caller
PutChar ENDP



;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Procedure to get a character from the console
;
; Given   :  The Address of the Character to get in ESI register
; Process :  Input the Character using the kernel32.lib ReadFile from the
;         :  Standard_Input function call.  No registers are changed and the
;         :  flags are not affected.
; Return  :  The input character in the data segment
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GetChar PROC NEAR32                         ; Define procedure
        pushad                          ; save all registers
        pushfd                          ; save flags
        INVOKE GetStdHandle,STD_INPUT   ; get handle for keyboard
        mov hStdIn, eax                 ; save the handle
        INVOKE SetConsoleMode,          ; invoke standard console with
        hStdIn,                         ;   file handle for keyboard
        ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT          ;   turn line buffering off
        INVOKE ReadFile,                ; invoke standard ReadFile with
          hStdIn,                       ;   file handle for keyboard
          esi,                          ;   address of character
          1,                            ;   length of one byte
          NEAR32 PTR read,              ;   variable for # bytes read
          0                             ;   overlapped mode
        call PutChar                    ; echo the character on screen
        popfd                           ; restore flags
        popad                           ; restore registers
        ret                             ; return to caller
GetChar   ENDP

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Procedure to convert a null terminated string into a word-sized unsigned number
;
;  Inputs: ESI points to null terminated string to convert
;          EDI points to location to store answer
;          BX contains number base of given number
;  Outputs: unsigned word stored in location that EDI points to
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Str2Num proc
        pushad                     ; save registers
        pushfd                     ; save flags

        ; initialize total to 0
        xor eax, eax                ; using accumulator for total
        xor ecx, ecx                ; zero out all of ecx

        ; loop through each character in string
        charLoop_str2num:

            ; if null terminator, exit loop
            cmp byte ptr [esi], 0
            je done_str2num

            ; if space terminator, exit loop
            cmp byte ptr [esi], ' '
            je done_str2num

            ; if not null, process
            ; weighted positional notation

            ; multiply total times base
            ; dx:ax = ax * bx
            mul bx

            ; convert digit to number and add to total
            mov cl, [esi]           ; move ascii character into register

            cmp cl, '9'             ; see if character is numeric digit
            jg isAlpha_str2num

            ; else, fall through... treat as numeric digit
        isNumeric_str2num:

            sub cl, '0'             ; converting character to number, ie. '1' => 1
            jmp addNumberToTotal

        isAlpha_str2num:

            ; make characters uppercase
            and cl, 0dfh            ; AND with 1101 1111 to turn off bit

            sub cl, 'A'             ; 'A'=0, 'B'=1, 'C'=2, ... 
            add cl, 10              ; 'A'=10, 'B'=11, 'C'=12, ...

        addNumberToTotal:

            add ax, cx              ; add number to total

            ;  increment pointer to next character
            inc esi

            ; continue with loop
            jmp charLoop_str2num

        done_str2num:

            ; number is in AX... let's store answer
            mov [edi], ax               

        popfd                      ; restore flags
        popad                      ; restore registers
        ret                        ; return to caller
Str2Num endp

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Procedure to convert a word-sized unsigned number into a null terminated string
;
;  Inputs: ESI points to unigned word-size integer to convert
;          EDI point to location to store null terminated string
;          BX contains number base of desired output string
;  Outputs: unsigned word stored in location that EDI points to
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Num2Str proc
        pushad                     ; save registers
        pushfd                     ; save flags

        mov ax, [esi]           ; move number into accumulator for divide remainder technique
        pushw 0                 ; push null terminator onto stack to mark position

        ; loop until zero
    divLoop:
        xor dx, dx                      ; prep dx register for divide
        div bx                  ; divide ax/bx

        ; remainder can be 0-9... or 10+
        cmp dx, 9
        jg alpha_num2str

        digit_num2str:
            add dx, '0'             ; convert number to ascii character, ie. 7=>'7'
            jmp push_num2str

        alpha_num2str:
            sub dl, 10              ; 10=>0, 11=>1, 12=>2, ...
            add dl, 'A'             ; 0=>A, 1=>B, 2=>C, ...

        push_num2str:
            push dx                 ; save character onto stack
            cmp ax, 0               ; if accum is zero... done with div remainder loop
            jne divLoop             ; if AX != 0... continue with divide remainder

    popCharacters:
        pop dx                  ; pop character off stack
        mov [edi], dl           ; store character onto string
        inc edi                 ; move pointer to next byte
        cmp dl, 0               ; check if null terminator
        jne popCharacters       ; if not null terminator, continue processing characters

    done_num2str:
        popfd                      ; restore flags
        popad                      ; restore registers
        ret                        ; return to caller
Num2Str endp



end  ; end directive to compiler
```

Comment: Narrow it down to a [mcve], thank you.

Comment: IDK what the problem is, but look up the standard ABI for your platform and use it, instead of writing functions that save/restore all registers and flags.  That's super-slow.  You might as well just write in C instead of writing *slow* asm.  Lots of good links at the http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info tag wiki page.

Comment: What are you using to view the files produced by the code? You're using OpenFileA and WriteFileA, which are both ANSI versions of the functions. Hearing mention of chinese characters immediately makes me think about encoding. Are you sure your viewer isn't interpreting the files as Unicode? A hex-editor will make it clear if this is a worthy avenue of investigation in short order.

Comment: @enhzflep notepad and sublime text. np shows it in Chinese chars and sublime shows hex values but they're in groups of 4 and not 2. that's the problem. I'm working on it now.

Comment: @lasec0203 - dunno, I dont use near8 or near32 when using **M**asm, preferring to stick undecorated type names. **Actually** are you sure that this isn't MASM syntax, it doesn't look anything like Nasm (.586 is an invalid directive, too)  I recommend you do some more debugging. Verify the contents of the buffer before the call to WriteFile, compare the contents of the buffer with the contents of the output file. Dont use a text-editor, use a hex editor - you need to see the file without any interpretation in order to make the debugging as straight-forward as possible. Re-read Jester's comment.

Comment: One thing I see is that after reading a line of text in from user with option 1, you `call Update_fdata` . The thing that seems to be missing is that *Update_fdata* doesn't actually update `numBytes` so when you go to option 3 to write the data output, it won't know how many bytes to write.

Comment: I'd use your debugger and break at `WriteFileContents` and check the values you are passing to CreateFileA. Are all the parameters correct with the values that make sense?

Comment: @MichaelPetch that was it. numBytes wasn't getting updated in my user procedure. Working on making an answer for this now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the 32-bit registers instead of the 8-bit registers in the Update_fdata procedure solved my problem with the Chinese characters showing in my created txt files.

```
     ;----------------------------------------------------------------------
     ; Procedure to copy outData into fdata
     ;----------------------------------------------------------------------
     Update_fdata  proc           ; Define procedure
        pushad                     ; save all registers
        pushfd                     ; save flags

        xor ecx, ecx
        lea esi, outData
        lea edi, fdata

        ;Copy Section
        Update_fdata_loop1:
            cmp byte ptr [esi], 0
            je done_Update_fdata

            mov eax, [esi]
            mov [edi], eax
            inc esi
            inc edi
            inc ecx 

        jmp Update_fdata_loop1
        ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

        done_Update_fdata:
        mov eax, 0
        mov [edi+1], eax        ;end EDI with null terminator
        inc ecx
        mov numBytes, ecx           ; now save value from eax into permanent variable


        popfd                      ; restore flags
        popad                      ; restore registers
        ret                        ; return to caller

   Update_fdata   endp
```

As @Michael Petch pointed out numBytes wasn't getting updated whenever I was copying over bytes in the Update_fdata procedure. This caused WriteFileContents unable to produce output to the out file. Using ECX as a counter and moving the value into numbytes at the end of the Update_fdata procedure corrected this issue.